# What should I call this commutative monoid of order three?

Tags: terminology, semigroups, monoid

I'm looking for a name for the monoid given by the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}&1&a&b\\ \hline
1&1&a&b\\
a&a&1&b\\
b&b&b&b
\end{array}
$$

Is there a name that would be understandable to an undergraduate student who hasn't read anything about semigroups but has had a first course in algebra and knows what a semigroup/monoid is? What name would it be good to go under in a list of order-three semigroups?

Comment: I'd call it $\{-1,0,1\}$, but I don't know very much about abstract algebra...

Comment: @RahulNarain Right. Thank you. This is really embarrassing.

Comment: Call it *Diego*, just for kicks.

Comment: @Asaf I haven't been so embarrassed for quite some time. Mocking may lead to an attempt at burying my head in the floor. That's probably safer than using sand, but still not a good idea. :)

Comment: @ymar, if you prefer we can give it a Polish name, *Stanislaw*, perhaps.

Comment: @Asaf That's my grandfather's name. I'm not sure he'd be honored though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call it : $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},*)$

Comment: Oh... Thanks! The way I looked at it I did not notice that $b$ was a zero element.

Comment: it was the first think i saw :)

Answer (score 1):

In computer science I would call it $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with errors, i.e. $ \langle \{0,1,\bot\},+,0\rangle $. In math I would follow hassan's idea.

Comment: Thanks. So if $G$ is a group, then $G^0$ ($G$ with zero adjoined) is called "$G$ with errors"?

Comment: @ymar Not zero, but an element that spreads like a virus (usually denoted by $\bot$). Any operation can result in an error $\bot$ (e.g. if you divide $1$ by $0$ in some algebra containing division) and if the "error result" is passed to any other expression, it propagates, i.e. the result of that expression has to be $\bot$ as well. Indeed, that kind of structures are denoted $G^\bot$, and called "$G$ with errors" or "$G$ with error handling". This is very similar to [NaNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) or monad `Maybe` from Haskell language (e.g. $G^\bot \cong \mathtt{Maybe}\ G$).